# jQuery override $.post function

Tags: jquery, function, post, methods, overriding

First of all I apologize for my poor english... Hope someone will understand my question and help me...

I'm working on a project using lots of $.post call and I want to improve them by adding the same verification for all of them.

I do not want to change all scripts one by one so is there any way to override the $.post function to add the same thing to all of them at the same time ?
Or maybe a way to trigger another function on each $.post ?
Something like :

```
$.post.each(function(){[...]});
```

or

```
$('body').on('post', function(){[...]});
```

Thanks !

EDIT :
Finally did it as I wanted !
Here is my code :

```
// Override $.post
(function(){
    // Store a reference to the original remove method.
    var originalPostMethod = jQuery.post;

    // Define overriding method.
    jQuery.post = function(data){
        // Execute the original method.
        var callMethod = originalPostMethod.apply( this, arguments);

        callMethod.success(function(){
            //console.log('success');
        });
        callMethod.error(function(){
            //console.log('error');
        });
        callMethod.complete(function(){
            //console.log('complete');
            return callMethod;
        });
    }
})();
```

Comment: Just to clarify something : I'm trying to override the $.post function and specially the 'success' and 'error' parts.

Answer (score 2):

```
$.post = function() {
  var _method = $.post;
  // do something you want
  console.log("do someting");
  return _method.apply($, Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments));
}
```

Comment: Thanks !
You're answer is really helpful !
I'm now able to override the $.post function !

`(function(){
  // Store a reference to the original remove method.
  var originalPostMethod = jQuery.post;

  // Define overriding method.
  jQuery.post = function(){
   // Log the fact that we are calling our override.
   console.log('override');

   // Execute the original method.
   originalPostMethod.apply( this, arguments );
  }
 })();`

But can you add some detail on how to override the 'success' and 'error' part of the $.post function ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a jQuery-Plug which does the validation and then posting the data to the Server. The basics can be found in the jQuery [tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring).