# Possible to add argument to all jQuery post calls?

Tags: jquery, ajax, security, csrf

I have an application where I have implemented CSRF protection by requiring all requests to the server to include a CSRF token.  I have many places in my application that use the jQuery post function like below:

```
$.post("/ajax/whatever", {data: "my data"}, function(data){
   //whatever
});
```

The above request will not work unless I include the CSRF token like below:

```
$.post("/ajax/whatever", {data: "my data", _csrf: "my_csrf_token"}, function(data){
   //whatever
});
```

Unfortunately this requires that I modify every single piece of code that uses the `post` function.

What I am wondering is if there is any way that I could intercept all calls to the `post` function and update the data being passed to include the missing CSRF token?  Can this be done?  Suggestions on where to start?

Comment: There is a global ajaxSend handler, however i'm not sure if it will let you modify the ajax options.

Comment: See also this [Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11930295/jquery-override-post-function)

Answer (score 0):

It is really easy to override a JQuery Function ;-)

```
var CSRF ="123456789";

(function(jQuery){
  var oPost = jQuery.post;
  jQuery.post = function( ) {
        if (!jQuery.isFunction( arguments[1] )) {
            arguments[1]['_csrf'] = CSRF;   
        }
    return oPost.apply($, Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments));
  };
})(jQuery)
```

Look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/skaZr/1/)

Comment: Hrrm is is possible to have an override that just updates the data and calls the original post function?